# jQuery Tab - load page only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Horizontal Tab [to load page once]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498851/horizontal-tab-to-load-page-once)

I need a jQuery horizontal tab pane where clicking on a tab loads an external page in the div, but clicking on it again does not load the page again !

**=========================================================================**

a demo can be seen here http://www.web-shine.in/tabs/

in the demo clicking on TAB 1 [when i clicked] shows page 1 content 11/04/02 12:16:59

clicking on TAB 2 shows page 2 content 11/04/02 12:17:05

clicking again on TAB 1 shows page 1 content 11/04/02 12:17:15  *[ correct jQuery code should show 11/04/02 12:16:59 ]*

**i want that TAB should load the page once, and next time the user clicks on it, it should show the page from browser cache, not from the server !**

**=========================================================================**

i found a similar problem @ [jQuery load page only once on tab click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509712/jquery-load-page-only-once-on-tab-click) but failed to learn from it !

i'm not good in jQuery, so i need someone who can re-write my code from the demo !

*i don't want to use any plug-in !*